# Tab bar Application

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

Greetings of the Day,

I am having issue in my app.Actually, in my app i am having five tabs bars each having navigation controllers each having table view, on clicking cell of table view another modal view controller is opening and clicking on button of modal view controller another  second modal view controller is opening where i am having one button to come back at first table view(home screen).I can come back to first modal view controller from last modal view controller by

```
[self dismissModalViewController];
```

i can come back to table view from 1st modal view controller by

```
[self dismissModalViewController];
```

but the need of an app is to come back directly at tableView(or home screen) while clicking on button of last modal view controller.

Now the issue is that i am unable to come back directly at tableView(or home screen) from second(or last) modal view controller.Could you please help me!!!!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```